# Change php config for laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess

I won't to change php version for laravel(7.2) project on .htaccess

for *.php I found this code, it working correctly

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php4|php5|php3|php2|php|phtml)$">
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74-lsphp
</FilesMatch>
```

for artisan I try this code but it not working

```
<Files artisan>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74-lsphp
</Files>
```

Comment: .htaccess is for Apache web server. Artisan is a CLI tool that doesn't use the web server, it calls PHP directly. If you want to use a different PHP version in CLI, you either need to call your commands with `/path/to/php7.4 thePHPScriptToRun`, or configure your OS to use 7.4 as default for CLI. How to do that depends on your OS and how you installed that PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

You can change php interpreter directly in artisan.

Change first line in **artisan.php** and set interpreter you want

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php7.4
<?php
//code
?>
```